# Could not resolve me.shedaniel:RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric:13.0.666

Tags: java, maven, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

So I am trying to add REI as an dependency to my mod, but it gives the error displayed in the title. I have watched a tutorial and did everything the same yet the build fails. I also tried to do it with create and got the same error.

This is my entire build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'fabric-loom' version '1.4-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

version = project.mod_version
group = project.maven_group

base {
    archivesName = project.archives_base_name
}

repositories {
    maven { url "<https://maven.shedaniel.me/>" }
    // Add repositories to retrieve artifacts from in here.
    // You should only use this when depending on other mods because
    // Loom adds the essential maven repositories to download Minecraft and libraries from automatically.
    // See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
    // for more information about repositories.
}

loom {
    runs {
        // This adds a new gradle task that runs the datagen API: "gradlew runDatagen"
        datagen {
            inherit server
            name "Data Generation"
            vmArg "-Dfabric-api.datagen"
            vmArg "-Dfabric-api.datagen.output-dir=${file("src/main/generated")}"
            vmArg "-Dfabric-api.datagen.modid=vixitumod"
 
            runDir "build/datagen"
        }
    }
}

// Add the generated resources to the main source set
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs += [
                    'src/main/generated'
            ]
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    // To change the versions see the gradle.properties file
    minecraft "com.mojang:minecraft:${project.minecraft_version}"
    mappings "net.fabricmc:yarn:${project.yarn_mappings}:v2"
    modImplementation "net.fabricmc:fabric-loader:${project.loader_version}"

    // Fabric API. This is technically optional, but you probably want it anyway.
    modImplementation "net.fabricmc.fabric-api:fabric-api:${project.fabric_version}"

    modCompileOnly "me.shedaniel:RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric:13.0.666"
    modRuntimeOnly "me.shedaniel:RoughlyEnoughItems-fabric:13.0.66"
    
    // Uncomment the following line to enable the deprecated Fabric API modules. 
    // These are included in the Fabric API production distribution and allow you to update your mod to the latest modules at a later more convenient time.

    // modImplementation "net.fabricmc.fabric-api:fabric-api-deprecated:${project.fabric_version}"
}

processResources {
    inputs.property "version", project.version

    filesMatching("fabric.mod.json") {
        expand "version": project.version
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    it.options.release = 17
}

java {
    // Loom will automatically attach sourcesJar to a RemapSourcesJar task and to the "build" task
    // if it is present.
    // If you remove this line, sources will not be generated.
    withSourcesJar()

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

jar {
    from("LICENSE") {
        rename { "${it}_${project.base.archivesName.get()}"}
    }
}

// configure the maven publication
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }

    // See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html for information on how to set up publishing.
    repositories {
        // Add repositories to publish to here.
        // Notice: This block does NOT have the same function as the block in the top level.
        // The repositories here will be used for publishing your artifact, not for
        // retrieving dependencies.
    }
}
```

And this is the full error:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'vixitumodfolder'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':modCompileOnly'.
> Could not find me.shedaniel:RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric:13.0.666.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - file:/C:/Users/vixitu/Desktop/vixitumodfolder/.gradle/loom-cache/remapped_mods/me/shedaniel/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric/13.0.666/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric-13.0.666.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/vixitu/.gradle/caches/fabric-loom/minecraftMaven/me/shedaniel/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric/13.0.666/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric-13.0.666.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/vixitu/Desktop/vixitumodfolder/.gradle/loom-cache/minecraftMaven/me/shedaniel/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric/13.0.666/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric-13.0.666.pom
> - https://maven.fabricmc.net/me/shedaniel/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric/13.0.666/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric-13.0.666.pom
> - https://libraries.minecraft.net/me/shedaniel/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric/13.0.666/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric-13.0.666.pom
> - https://libraries.minecraft.net/me/shedaniel/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric/13.0.666/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric-13.0.666.jar
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/me/shedaniel/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric/13.0.666/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric-13.0.666.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/vixitu/Desktop/vixitumodfolder/https:/maven.shedaniel.me//me/shedaniel/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric/13.0.666/RoughlyEnoughItems-api-fabric-13.0.666.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: What is the question? You have the solution clear.